# Upload file and textbox detail in database using JSP

Tags: jsp, file-upload, clob

i want to upload a file with the new file name and that name also take from the user in JSP
how can simultaneously handle both ServletContext for file upload and HttpServletRequest form handle the form filed..

Please

Code::

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     File Name:
     <input type="text" name='filenm' />
     <input type="file" name="myFile" />
     <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

which file name is given that is give the name of file in jsp..
how can i handle this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you: http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2013/07/ile-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp-java-web-tutorial-example.html Didn't try it but looks like something that could help you.

**EDIT:**

Sorry I didn't understand what exactly you are trying to do because in your question you are saying something about php and jsp and I don't know how these work together because I had never anything to do with jsp.

But your problem is that you don't know how to get the input text value, right?
The jsp equivalent to $_POST['filenm'] seems to be request.getParameter("filenm").toString() if that helps you.

**another EDIT:**
Maybe something like this could work:

```
//process only if its multipart content
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
            try {
                List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                                         new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

            for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                if(!item.isFormField()){
                    String name = request.getParameter("filenm");
                    item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do u want to do that with PHP?

Comment: i want in JSP not in PHP.. nd my problem is not to get value of text box but i cant handle both at a time... pls understand whole question that why i give in detail

Comment: Do you want to upload your file to the Database ?

Comment: Did you try to combine the tutorial code from above with the input name variable like in my new edit?

Comment: no i don't but i want to upload my file in simple server folder and that file name i give in to the textbox that will be set

Comment: Please show us the jsp code you re using otherwise we re not able to help you.